# How to determine the page URL at run time in Javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, url, web

I want to determine the URL of a page in Javascript. Is this possible?
How can I achieve this?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [`window.location` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location).

Depending on whether you want the hash, query string etc there are many different properties available.

For instance, on this page;

```
window.location.hash: "#11537761";
window.location.host: "stackoverflow.com";
window.location.hostname: "stackoverflow.com";
window.location.href: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537718/how-to-determine-the-page-url-at-run-time-in-javascript/11537761#11537761";
window.location.origin: "http://stackoverflow.com";
window.location.pathname: "/questions/11537718/how-to-determine-the-page-url-at-run-time-in-javascript/11537761";
```

Comment: Thank you all! this was the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

A quick google:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
  alert(location.href);
</SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript you have [document.URL](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-46183437)

```
alert(document.URL);
```